# fancyhdr headings , how to remove the number of the section

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm French so it's not easy to explain my problem but I'll try.

I use fancyhdr to make my own headings (book class).

I want the section's title at the right of the heading in small caps, and only in odds pages. But when I print it I can read e.g., "2. DERIVATION" which is what I was expecting.

My question is: how can I remove the number of the section, so that I can obtain just "DERIVATION" and not "2.DERIVATION"?

I wrote :

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0 pt}
```

`\leftmark` is for chapter and is OK.

The problem is with the `\rightmark`, how can I redefine it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 8):

Add the following line to the settings for **fancyhdr**

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
```

Comment: @egreg I cannot seem to make your solution work with my setup. I have `\rhead{\rightmark}` + your code.

Comment: @macmadness86 Difficult to say without an example; open a new question and don't forget a MWE.

Comment: @egreg Another question would be a duplicate of this question. I am not sure that this is a good idea. This is an example of how the "one question per issue" policy does not always work.

Comment: @macmadness86 Why should it be a duplicate? I retested the solution with a minimal preamble and it works. So your problem depends on what you're loading. Also the documentclass can be important: for instance, if you're using `article` with the `twoside` option.

Comment: @egreg My question would be "How can remove the section number from the marks in fancyhdr" or something to that effect. I have a one-sided document with `article` class. The `geometry` package is also in there.

Comment: @macmadness86 The presented solution works for me. Please, open a new question with a minimal example showing the issue.

Comment: For completeness, here is the link to the new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222370/13552