# How do I remove page numbers without impact table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I'm currently using `\pagenumbering{gobble}` because I don't want page numbers
at the bottom of my pages. But I still want them to appear in the
`\tableofcontents`.

What is a method of removing page numbers from the pages
without removing them from `\tableofcontents`?

I can't use `\pagestyle{empty}` since I am using `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: WHat about using `\pagestyle{empty}`?

Comment: @Guido because my pagestyle is already fancy

Comment: What about something like `\fancyfoot[C]{}` in the definition of your fancy pagestyle... (assuming your page number is in the center? Cf. to the definition of pagestyles e.g. here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24137/fancyhdr-headings-how-to-remove-the-number-of-the-section?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your target is not to remove all bottom numbers in a document, but to remove those bottom numbers associated with the particular pages that are listed on the table of contents (with page numbers intact).

The `\fancypagestyle{nopagenum}{...}` command is used to define a new page style, and then issue the command `\thispagestyle{nopagenum}` right below those commands that will write contents to TOC.

To demonstrate, I write up a `test.tex` using typical fancy header setting

[image]

You will see that pages 3, 5, 7 and 9 are removed if the file is complied. (Sorry there are a total of 9 pages and I did not post them all to save space.)

Code:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1 pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1 pt}
%
\fancypagestyle{nopagenum}{%         % This is what you need
\fancyfoot[C]{}                      % page number at center is assumed
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter1}
\thispagestyle{nopagenum}            % called to remove bottom page number
\lipsum[1-5]
\newpage
\section{Section 1.1}
\thispagestyle{nopagenum}            %
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Chapter2}
\thispagestyle{nopagenum}            %
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section 2.1}
\thispagestyle{nopagenum}            %
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well you could also just ommit the `\thepage` in line 9 instead of the `nopagenum` stuff :)

Comment: @Ronny -- I did do that when I was attacking the problem. But that will disable the numbering of regular pages (i.e., those not on TOC).

Comment: Well, the OP just states, he doesn't want “pagenumbers at the bottom of the page” (as I understand, no pagenumbers in foot) but his `\gobble` does of course also produce a TOC without pagenumbers (and just setting the foot to empty keeps numbers in TOC) - therefore - IMHO - just one pagestyle should be enough, that uses your line 14 :)

Comment: Oh..OK, for that case, line 14 suffices. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
This is a test
\clearpage
\section{Next}
This continues the test
\end{document}
```

---

[image: Output]

---